# Else if Statement Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

Can anybody help me make this work, the idea is , if a post, retrieve one stylesheet, if the homepage another, if not, assume it's a page and use that stylesheet. the home and the post ones work, but it detects the pages as the homepage and not a page, any help?

```
<?php
if ( ! is_single() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/pageSpecific/index.css">
<?php
} elseif ( ! is_home() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/pageSpecific/post.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles/pageSpecific/page.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<?php }?>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems odd the way it is being used... Try the following (taking the ! out of the if/else

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
    //your stylesheet for single

<?php } elseif ( is_home() ) { ?>
    //Your stylesheet for home

<?php } else { ?>
    //Your everything else stylesheet

<?php }?>
```

using the ! you are going to get this logic
if is not single //anything that is not a home or page will apply this so it will not get to the else

using it without the ! will go clear to the else statement if it is not a single or home.  Then it will apply the stylesheet of the else.  the way you have it .  if you are seeing your homepage, it is not a single so it will stop there.

Comment: Thankyou this was very useful, just needed to switch post and page and it works, thanks again!

Comment: No problem... I changed my answer to show only comments in the if to make it a bit more universal to help out others with this question.  Glad I could help!  Dont forget to accept answers